# Exercise 3.30 from Görtz-Wedhorn: local affine algebras

Tags: commutative-algebra

Here's the Exercise 3.30 from [the textbook of Görtz and Wedhorn](https://www.springer.com/book/9783834806765):

> Let $k$ be a field, and let $A$ be a local $k$-algebra of finite type.
>   Prove that $\operatorname{Spec} A$ consists of a single point, and
>   that $A$ is finite-dimensional as a $k$-vector space. In particular
>   $A$ is a local Artin ring (why?), and $\kappa (A)/k$ is a finite field
>   extension.

I see how this follows from some well-known results:

1. Every finitely generated algebra over a Jacobson ring is Jacobson, so that $A$ is Jacobson. As $A$ is local, this amounts to saying that its maximal ideal is the only prime ideal.
2. In general, for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ in a finitely generated $k$-algebra $A$, the extension $\kappa (\mathfrak{m})/k$ is finite (which follows again from the general results about Jacobson rings).
3. A ring is Artinian iff it is Noetherian and every prime ideal is maximal, which is the case here.
4. A finitely generated $k$-algebra is Artinian iff it is finite (Atiyah-Macdonald, Exercise 8.3).

However, all this seems to be an overkill, and I think the authors had in mind some direct argument for the very special case when $A$ is local. Do you see one?

Comment: Just an opinion, but this doesn't seem like overkill to me.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the finite type and I think you need finite(i.e. integrality condition.) For finite type, I assume you mean finitely generated over $k$. However, consider $k[x,y]$ and localize away from $(x,y)=(0,0)$ points. This gives a local ring of dimension 2 and this is finite type over $k$. The spectrum cannot be made of single point. If it is made of 1 point, one would expect this had better be a finite field extension as indicated in the conclusion.

Comment: @user45765 Every algebra of finite type over a field is a Jacobson ring, and a Jacobson ring is local when its maximal ideal is the only prime ideal. (See e.g. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00FZ for the statements and proofs.) So a local ring of dimension $> 0$ can't be of finite type over a field.